# How do I ignore characters in Lex?

Tags: c, lex

Is it possible to completely ignore certain characters in Lex? Any regex excluding characters will break apart the tokens where those characters occur rather than completely ignoring them. I am aware of the semicolon rule wherein the text is ignored; however, including a regex later on that accepts any characters still accepts characters previously declared to be ignored. Having that regex ignore those characters causes it to break the token when it meets them instead of skipping past them.

Comment: You could redefine `YY_INPUT` to a custom input function which skips those characters.

Comment: Are you limited to the feature set of POSIX `lex`, or can you perhaps assume that your `lex` is actually GNU `flex`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I am currently using `lex`, but I could change if `flex` has an easier way of doing this than redefining `YY_INPUT`

Comment: @mwpuppire, POSIX and original AT&T `lex` do not have even `YY_INPUT`, at least not as a documented feature.  That's `flex`-specific.  But chances are fairly high, especially if you're on Linux, that your `lex` is really `flex` already.  This is what I am asking, as well as whether you're ok with being `flex`-specific.  It sounds like the answer at least to the latter is "yes".

Comment: @JohnBollinger, In that case, I am okay with `flex` specific code.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The classic problem which might require this feature is splicing continuation lines in C (which has the unfortunate characteristic of being able to splice in the middle of a token). But for most use cases, it's sufficient to accumulate token pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to completely ignore certain characters in Lex?

No, original AT&T `lex` utility does not have anything that would support this, nor does POSIX specify any such thing.  Input is read from the specified stream, and matched directly against provided patterns.  Every character obtained from the input is subject to matching -- only before `lex` reads it in or after it tokenizes is there an opportunity to muck with character content.

It would be possible, but extremely messy to write a ruleset and corresponding actions that acted *as if* some specified character were completely ignored.  Instead, your best bet is to ensure that the characters in question are stripped out before `lex` ever sees them.

With traditional and POSIX `lex`, data are read from a stream designated to the lexer via global stream pointer `yyin`.  Standard C provides no mechanism for wrapping or internally filtering streams, but you *could* insert an external filter by having your program fork, with the child reading the original input data, stripping out the unwanted characters, and piping the rest to the parent process.  The parent, meanwhile, wraps the read end of the pipe in a stream (`fdopen()`, for example), and assigns that to `yyin`.

On the other hand, if you use Flex instead of traditional `lex` then you have the alternative of redefining the [`YY_INPUT()`](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#Generated-Scanner) macro to filter out the unwanted characters before they reach the scanner proper.  This is lighter-weight than forking, and it can be expressed in the `flex`'s input file, rather than requiring the the program using the scanner to set up the filter.

Either way, however, there is no built-in feature specifically for pretending that particular characters did not appear in the input at all.

Comment: `popen` might be a simpler solution for a filter, provided you're using a  Posix(-like) system. (And if you aren't, you might not have `fork` either.)